# Server on Physical HDD from dead server needs Converting into Virtual Machine

Tags: hard-drive, vmware, windows-server-2003

I have dead server wich need reviving, all i managed to retrieve is HDD, is there an easy way of converting this physical HDD into any virtual format that VMWare converter could use?

So far i've used Disk2VHD but VHD is not supported by the VMWare converter...

Comment: You could just convert VHD to the format used by WmWare.  I promise that there are tools that exist to do just that.  Which tools have you used?

Comment: Well, best way i found about doing this is as follows:
Attached HDD to my laptop and using Disk2VHD coverted it to .VHD
Then used WinImage to convert .VHD to .VMDK
And lastly uploaded it to vSphere.

But is was a lengthy process, if anyone knows how that can be done quicker, please let me know.

Comment: You can skip most of that process by using VM softwar which supports the .VHD file format.  Or use a tool similar to Disk2VHD that makes a .VMDK image isntead.

Comment: After i finished this i uploaded the VMDK file to new machine but it blue screens everytime it tries to start a server... is there any other ways to do it only having dead server HDD?

Answer (score 1):

Could you hook up the hard drive to a spare Windows machine? You could then create an ISO file of the HDD using a tool like [this](http://www.ntfs.com/iso_file_manager.htm) and then run the ISO through VMWare/VirtualBox?

Comment: I did a similar thing (as commented on my post), but it took a very long time, if any quicker ways are known i would love to hear them.